# Is it possible to do a query for a specific value, whereby it is increased by a percentage?

Tags: sql, string

This may seem like a hard question to understand; I'm brand new to any types of coding and scripting and therefore I cannot explain this better than I have, sorry :)

I have been tasked with writing and executing a query for the following requests: "Output the sales order ID, order date, subtotal, and the **tax amount increased by 2.5% for each sales order."** That last section is where the problem arises. I have been able to bring up a super simple table by just entering:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, SubTotal, TaxAmt
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader
```

When I executed this the table worked as intended, but my problem comes when I am asked to have the tax amount "increased by 2.5%"; what does this mean?

Again, sorry if my explanation isn't very useful; it's the best I can provide.

If you need any extra information, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add like this.

```
SELECT (TaxAmt * 1.025) as tax
```

Comment: haha, it still helped either way, especially for a newbie like me :)

Comment: Done! I tried to accept both before (I've now realised you can't do that) and I had to wait a bit

Answer (score 2):

Well, my first guess would be:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, SubTotal,
       (TaxAmt * 1.025) as TaxAmt
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader;
```

Comment: Thank you friend! You don't know how much that helped me!